# Pasar un parametro de una vista al controlador

Tags: ruby-on-rails, insert

Estoy trantando de pasar un parametro directamente desde la vista index a mi accion create, para que almacene dicho parametro en la bd junto a el id del usuario actual, pero solo se redirigue a otra direccion y no esta almacenando la informacion.

index.html.erb

```
  <tbody> 
        <% @pets.each do |pet| %>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="<%= pet_path(pet) %>"> <%= pet.name %></a></td>
                <td>
                    <% @users.each do |user| %>
                        <% @sponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
                            <% if user.id == sponsor.user_id and pet.id == sponsor.pet_id %>
                                | <a href="<%= user_path(pet) %>"> <%= user.email%> </a> |
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= link_to "Apadrinar", {:controller => "sponsors", :action => "create", :mascot => pet.id }%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

mi controlador tiene

```
def create
 @sponsor = Sponsor.new(sponsor_params)
 @sponsor.assign_attributes({:user_id => current_user.id})
 @sponsor.assign_attributes({:pet_id => params[:mascot]})

 if @sponsor.save
     flash[:success] = "Felicidades usted, ahora es Padrino. Gracias por apoyarnos"
     redirect_to sponsors_path()
 else
     flash.now[:danger] = "La Historia no se ha podido crear, por favor revise los campos"
     render 'new'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de una forma parcial, no se si hay mejores. cambiando de la accion create a la accion new asi como cambiando mi funcion a new.

```
 def new
  @sponsor = Sponsor.new(sponsor_params)
  @sponsor.assign_attributes({:user_id => current_user.id})
  @sponsor.assign_attributes({:pet_id => params[:mascot]})

  if (Sponsor.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:pet_id => params[:mascot]).count == 0)
      if @sponsor.save
          flash[:success] = "Felicidades usted, ahora es Padrino. Gracias por apoyarnos"
          redirect_to sponsors_path()
      else
          flash.now[:danger] = "Ocurrió un error no se ha podido apadrinar la mascota"
          redirect_to sponsors_path()
      end
  else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Ya eres Pasdrino de esa Mascota"
      redirect_to sponsors_path()
  end
 end
```

Y en la vista quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
  <tbody> 
        <% if @pets %>
            <% @pets.each do |pet| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="<%= pet_path(pet) %>"> <%= pet.name %></a></td>
                    <td>
                        <% @users.each do |user| %>
                            <% @sponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
                                <% if user.id == sponsor.user_id and pet.id == sponsor.pet_id %>
                                    | <a href="<%= user_path(pet) %>"> <%= user.email%> </a> |
                                <% end %>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to "Apadrinar", {:controller => "sponsors", :action => "new", :mascot => pet.id }%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Cualquier otra solución que pueda dar soporte al problema. Por favor comentarla. =)